# How to match part of string using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

Here's the string :

```
SCOPE OF WORK: Supply &  Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,     PAN#: AAYCS8310G
installation Arumbakkam,Chennai,Tamil Nadu,
  xxxxxx
```

The things that will change in the string are:

```
Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,
```

and

```
Arumbakkam,Chennai,Tamil Nadu,
```

And these parts of the strings can contain alphabets , numbers , commas,#,- and _

The remaining parts of the string will remain as it is, including spacings.

Here's the regex I am using

```
SCOPE OF WORK: Supply &  [A-Za-z,\s]]*PAN#: [A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}\n    installation [A-Za-z]\n      xxxxxx
```

Ultimately what I need to obtain is:

```
Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,     
installation Arumbakkam,Chennai,Tamil Nadu,
```

I don't think my regex is entirely right and I need help on how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I noticed about your current pattern:

- You are trying to match more space characters than pressent in text;
- Your character classes for both substrings differ. There is spaces and comma missing from the 2nd one which is also only matched once. + Both are missing the `#` symbol and digits currently;

Assuming you need to just get these two substring in groups (excluding the trailing comma), try:

```
^SCOPE OF WORK: Supply &  ([\w, #-]+),\s+PAN#: [A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]\s+installation ([\w, #-]+),\s+x{6}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4xdzfU/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `SCOPE OF WORK: Supply &`   - A literal match of this substring including the two trailing spaces;
- `([\w, #-]+)` - A 1st capture group to match 1+ characters from given class where `\w` is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, all characters you mentioned it needs to include;
- `,\s+PAN#:`  - A literal match of this substring including the trailing comma and 1+ whitespace characters;
- `[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]` - Verification what follows is 5 uppercase letter, 4 digits and a single uppercase (no need to quantify a single character);
- `\s+installation`  - 1+ Whitespace characters including newline and trailing spaces upto;
- `([\w, #-]+)` - A 2nd capture group to match the same pattern as 1st group;
- `,\s+x{6}` - Match the trailing comma, 1+ whitespace characters and 6 trailing x's;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

---

```
import re

s = """SCOPE OF WORK: Supply &  Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,     PAN#: AAYCS8310G
installation Arumbakkam,Chennai,Tamil Nadu,
  xxxxxx"""
  
l = re.findall(r'^SCOPE OF WORK: Supply &  ([\w, #-]+),\s+PAN#: [A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]\s+installation ([\w, #-]+),\s+x{6}$', s)

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[('Flensburg House, MMDA Colony', 'Arumbakkam,Chennai,Tamil Nadu')]
```